# Is it possible to arrange ordering/sequence of handledmenuitem in frangment.e4xmi

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp, e4

I have eclise rcp applications, I have added menu items using handledmenuitem in frangment.e4xmi.
But I want to arrange those in some sequence. for example [image]

This is the menu items, but these are placed in order help - log - dg -apdu - validation
but I want those into the order of log - validation - help - dg -apdu.
How can I achieve this ? please note that some menu items are from different projects (I mean I have 3 different fragment.e4xmi for these menu items).

Answer (score 0):

In your main Application.e4xmi add `Separator` items to the menu and give them unique ids, you can turn off 'to be rendered' if you don't want the separator shown. Arrange them in the order you want the menu items to show.

For example:
[image: Example menu]

Then in your fragment.e4xmi use a Menu Contribution to add to the menu and specify a Position for the menu item, something like:

```
after=separator-id
```

For example:
[image: Example menu contribution]

Comment: Yes Thanks, I have already done it by adding entries directly into Application.e4xmi and it worked ...!!!